# clean install of windows 7, causes loss of internet connection to all other pcs in the same workgroup

Tags: windows-7, networking, ethernet

I have a PC, which lies in an office workgroup and has a product key on its side. I downloaded the corresponding Windows 7 ISO image, with this product key, and when I make a clean install, immediately, all PCs in the network, loose the internet connection. We use a router, and then a switch.

Why, whenever during the installation, when a certain level of progress is reached, all network connections are lost?

Finally, the license for the Windows 7 is a DSP one, so i should download from a special link?

Comment: check your dhcp settings.

Answer (score 0):

Since this happened to me once, I have an empirical solution.

From experience, the solution seems to be disconnecting the system before attempting to install Windows. (This has later become a security practice: I keep the systems disconnected until I install Windows, security software and a host of updates.) Of course, I ultimately connect the system to the network to join the domain and activate Windows.